# Python imread() don't work correctly with variable strings

Tags: python, opencv, filedialog, imread

I want to make a program in python to manipulate an image. The problem is I want to get the image by user input on file dialog but when I use a variable string named `file_path` it does not read on `cv2.imread()` function.

I suppose the problem is with the two slash problem on python. When we try to read an image path with one slash like `c:\XXX\X.png`, we get an error. The solution is `c:\\XXX\\X.png`, but with a string variable I cannot get solution?

Is there a solution for this problem?

```
import cv2

import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import filedialog

import numpy as np


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

#where i get path of image
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title = 'Select File', filetypes = [('image files', '.png;.jpg'), ('image files!', '*.png;*.jpg')])

# i get bug here below. It does even not show error text
image = cv2.imread(file_path)


# ... REST OF CODE
```

Comment: Use `filedialog.askopenfilename()`, instead (note lack of 's' at the end).  You're getting back a tuple or list of filenames, even if only one file was selected, which of course isn't something you can pass to `imread()`.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the problem :).